# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

My file directory:

```
project/src/m2mcom/entities/AutomatedTelnetClient.java
           /web/Simple.java           
           /org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.java
```

The source code of the Simple.java:

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
            String answer = telnet.request();
            System.out.println(answer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

And when I execute Simple.class, without any errors of compilation, I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\project2\src\m2mcom\web>java Simple
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Simple (wrong name: m
2mcom/web/Simple)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at this link you will understand why you get that error and how to avoid it in the future http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Answer (score 36):

You're executing the command in the wrong folder, with the wrong classname. You need to use the fully qualified name (FQN) when running a Java class. And of course, you have to be in the right directory. In your example, the FQN of your class is m2mcom.web.Simple (combination of the **package** `m2mcom.web` and the **simple** name `Simple`).

As far as deducing the right directory, your classes are stored in a hierarchical folder structure, which basically starts in `C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\project2\src`.

So to correctly execute your program, from `C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\project2\src`, do;

```
java m2mcom.web.Simple
```

Comment: You need to use fully qualified names when running Java classes, and you were also running the program in the wrong folder.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear answer, Perception!

Answer (score 5):

```
package m2mcom.web;
```

remove above line and recompile it.
when you run your code in netbeans it including in a m2mcom.web package.that is not in your class file.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to be in the directory right above the package name when you execute the java command which should be in the form packagename.classname without the .class suffix.