# Java class will not run (command prompt)

Tags: java, command, runtime, noclassdeffounderror, prompt

I have been fighting with this program for a little while now and cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So here's the issue. I have three classes one is for logging onto a mysql database, the other is to output data from the database, and the last one holds method main. I was having a huge issue with getting them to compile getting errors about not finding a symbol for a method in a different class. I finally got them to all compile by using command `"javac -d bin/cdtPack src/CDT.java src/login.java src/ClientBase.java"`

But, now when I try to run the class with method main I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.noClassDefFoundError: CDT (wrong
>   name: cdtPack/CDT)

then a list of at java....

Anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: It looks like `CDT` should either belong in the package `cdtPack` or you are running it from the wrong directory...try changing into the `bin\cdtPack` directory and run the class file again?

Comment: If that doesn't help, look at the other Google & SO hits for "java.lang.noClassDefFoundError" "wrong name".

Comment: This website is confusing me so I don't know how to pick your answer @MadProgrammer, but when I backed up to the bin directory it runs. :D

Comment: @user2713086 I made the comment an answer, let me know if I need to elaborate it further.  Glad you got it to work though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CDT should either belong in the package `cdtPack` or you are running it from the wrong directory...

Try changing into the `bin` directory and run the `class` file again.  Don't forget to include the `package` name before the `class` name. For example:

```
...\bin> java cdtPack.CDT
```

Comment: I don't think that will work.

Comment: @StephenC It will if the `CDT` belongs to the default package.  If `CDT` was in suppose to be in the `cdtPack` package I would agree.  But given the fact that the OP used `javac -d bin/cdtPack ...` to compile the classes, I believe they are in the default package ... I could be completely wrong of course ;)

Comment: The fact that the JVM says that the name in the class is "cdtPack/CDT" means that it must have a `package` statement.

Comment: @StephenC So, given `src/CDT.java` is the source file, we can assume that it should have a package statement.  Wouldn't this produce a compiler error?

Comment: No it wouldn't.  Try it and see.

Comment: @StephenC Just did, that's annoying :P

Answer (score 1):

As the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520793/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name) explains this happens when you try to run a Java application using the wrong class name.

Your class looks something like this:

```
package cdtPack;
public class CDT {
    ....
}
```

That means that its class name is "cdtpack.CDT".

But you are running it like this:

```
$ java CDT
```

The JVM is telling you this:

> "You told me to run CDT, but when I looked at it, the class said its name is "cdtpack.CDT"!!"

You have to get your head around the way that the Java classpath works, and the way that `javac` and `java` and all of the other Java tools find classes.

Your "CDT.class" file should be in a directory called "cdtpack", and then "cdtpack"'s *parent* directory should be on the classpath; i.e.

Compile like this:

```
$ javac -d bin -classpath bin src/cdtpack/CDT.java
```

which should create "bin/cdtpack/CDT.class".  Then run like this:

```
$ java -classpath bin cdtpack.CDT
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

you goto src directory and if class file available there, then type

**java CDT**

if the class is present in some other directory then type

**java a/b/c/JavaClassName**

if you want to add some runtime jar while running then

**java -cp classpath=%classpath%;jarfilename.jar;   a/b/c/JavaClassName**