# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: calculator (wrong name: apackage/calculator)

Tags: java, command, prompt

I'm trying to run my Java Class file from command prompt, when I try and do so I receive this error

```
C:\Users\New User\workspace\myproject\bin\apackage>java calculator -cp .
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: calculator (wrong nam
e: apackage/calculator)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried many different methods (setting classpaths and paths) and I haven't been able to solve this, any help would be appreciated C:

Comment: did you do the code in eclipse? eclipse normally uses packages, so you should call the classes using appropriate packing·

Comment: First, your `-cp` switch should be before your class name. Second, is your `calculator` class in package named `apackage` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520793/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name)

Answer (score 1):

After you have compiled the source (calculator.java), do the following:

Go to directory `C:\Users\New User\workspace\myproject\bin` in your command shell

```
C:\Users\New User\workspace\myproject\bin>java -cp . apackage.calculator
```

As your class in `apackage`, you need to run it from the root of your package structure - i.e. `bin`

EDIT: And yeah, you need to provide the `-cp` switch before the class name. Refer to `java` command help (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it out :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then your class is  `apackage.calculator`, and you're currently here

```
C:\Users\New User\workspace\myproject\bin\apackage>
```

then

```
C:\Users\New User\workspace\myproject\bin\apackage> cd ..\
... \bin> java -cp . apackage.calculator
```

Comment: I tried this but I recieved: "Error: Could not find or load main class calculator"

Comment: @user3910313 Edited. I had a copy paste issue.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

Please check calculator class file is available or not.